# ¿Cómo agregar un elemento i de html a un enlace en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy agregando html desde javascrpt pero necesito agregar un elemento `i` y no lo logro.

```
$('<a>').addClass('btn btn-light').attr('href','#').appendTo(oPic);

$('<i>').attr('class','fas fa-arrow-down'); // quiero agregar este elemento junto a su clase al enlace de arriba y no lo he podido lograr.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $a = $('<a>').addClass('btn btn-light').attr('href','#');
$a.appendTo(oPic);

$('<i>').attr('class','fas fa-arrow-down').appendTo($a);
```

Comment: Ese código es parte de una galería que al hacer scroll va mostrando las demás fotos, al agregar tu opción no funciona la carga de fotos con el scroll.

Comment: Disculpa, me funcionó el problema era que estaba colocando el símbolo de $ en la variable. Gracias!